# Texts of Currently Used Prayers for a Monarch

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, malchut-royalty

I am looking for the texts of *currently used* prayers for monarchs/royal families around the world.  I was able to easily find the  text of the British Jewish community's prayer for the royal family (linked [here](https://www.theus.org.uk/sites/default/files/ocrPrayer%20For%20The%20Royal%20Family%202014_0.pdf)), but there are many longstanding Jewish communities in various monarchies, in Europe and the Commonwealth realms particularly (as well as in more far flung monarchies, like Bahrain).  If a prayer does not exist for the royal family of a monarchy with a longstanding Jewish community, I would be interested to know that as well.

Comment: There's a prayer commonly used in the United States, and another commonly used in Israel. Are you asking only and specifically about prayers for monarchs, as your wording implies strongly, or generally about prayers for governments and governors?

Comment: @msh210 Just prayers for monarchs!

Comment: There's one in Norway if you can find a copy of a Norwegian Siddur (or if I remember correctly a Swedish Siddur since it's the same publisher)